# Order a list of sets based on a rule (pretty tough)

Tags: algorithms, combinations, pattern-recognition

I did not know where to turn so I'm looking up anyone who could offer an answer to this interesting problem.

I have a set of variables, listed as (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H)

Each variable is couple in a set and can both be the same variable
Example: (A/A, A/B, A/C, A/D etc...)

This makes 64 different combinations.

I am attempting to make a list of sets using a rule that will have the bottom half of the set (A/B) start the top half of the next set (B/C) And so on... (C/D, D/E, E/F)

The goal here is to have all 64 sets in this manner.

What is the order of all 64 combinations in order, using the rule described? I have been trying to figure this out for a long time and I don't know if it's even possible.

Thank you in advance. I hope you can help me with this seemingly impossible problem :)

Comment: The difficult part is when you first encounter e.g. $A/A$.  What will the following element be?  You have already given a good starting arrangement for the first eight elements, can you perhaps put the $x/x$ elements between incremental sets?

Comment: thats exactly the issue I'm encountering. The following element to A/A would be A/X, X being whatever you want. so naturally, it would look like:

A/A, A/B, B/C, C/D, D/E, E/F, F/G, G/H, H/H... etc etc

But when I do certain orders of this, somewhere I wind up having to use a set of elements twice, which results in a failed formula. Something tells me that there is a single answer that is correct. I just haven't been able to find it...

Comment: My suggestion would be to try $\{A/A, A/B, B/C, ..., G/H, H/H, H/A, A/C, C/G, G/A, A/E, E/G, G/C, C/E, E/A,...\}$ as a start.  Is this similar to what you have already tried?

Comment: Right. What winds up happening is you run into double use at a second A/B: 
(A/A, A/B, B/C, C/D, D/E, E/F, F/G, G/H, H/H, H/A, A/B) 
So substitute A/B for A/C and get D/E again: 
(A/A, A/B, B/C, C/D, D/E, E/F, F/G, G/H, H/H, H/A, A/C, C/B, B/D, D/E)
So we substitute E for F: 
(A/A, A/B, B/C, C/D, D/E, E/F, F/G, G/H, H/H, H/A, A/C, C/B, B/D, D/F, F/G...)

Comment: No, if you noticed, I did $A/A$ then the cycle of $x/x+1$, then $H/H$, then the cycle of $2x-1/2x+1$ intermixed with $2x-1/2x+3$; remaining cycles include $3x-k/3x-m$, $2x+1/2x-1$, $2x/2x\pm 2$, $2x/2x+4$, $x/x-1$.  There should be no duplicates in any of these cycles.

Comment: Focusing on the formula for each cycle should help ensure that there are no overlaps.

Comment: I See... sadly I am confused with this. so let me attempt to clarify:

X/X+1 could be represented by the set:
A/A, A/B, B/C, C/D, D/E, E/F, F/G, G/H

Then you input H/H, which begins a new set. Then you said the next cycle is 2x - 1/2x + 1. 

Can you explain what that exactly means? Would that mean you double H then subtract 1? I'm thinking in terms of A = 1, B = 2 etc, then when 8 is reached, 9 would be 1, since it loops back around and 0 is not part of the variable set.

Comment: Exactly.  Actually, $H/H$ followed by $H/A$ is the conclusion of the first set, then $A/C=2x-1/2x+1$ is the first of the second set.  The $x/x$ terms can be placed anywhere in the set, including simply interspersed with the first cycle, to make sure they get placed.

Comment: There is a problem I've found with the formulas you gave me. I solved for x/x+1 which worked out fine. Then I tried 2x-1/2x+1 and that didn't work out since if x = 1, you get 1/3, but if x = 5, you still get 1/3. The next formula, 2x-1/2x+3 did not work out. It didn't follow the rule. I'm trying out all of them to see which ones fit, then gonna try to find more formulas that work out. :D thank you very much.

Comment: For $x=5, 2x-1/2x+1$ is wrapped around too far, and the intent was to stop at $x=4$ for that formula.

Comment: so each has to stop before wrapping around? how else do I use the formulas properly?

Comment: Yes, for each formula, only continue the cycle until where it would repeat.  Otherwise it would defeat the point of your exercise.

Comment: I still don't understand how this creates 64 different sets if the formula has to be shortened. Maybe I'm just totally understanding how you are putting the formula together. Do you mind working the problem and listing the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint: You are looking for an [Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) in the complete graph on 8 vertices. The set of vertices being $\{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H\}$, and the edge from $x$ to $y$ being denoted $x/y$ by you.

(Actually, I may be misusing the term “complete graph” here, since your graph also contains all the loops $x/x$.)

**Edit:** On second thought, your graph is a directed graph, with two oppositely directed arrows between any two different vertices, and just one from a vertex to itself. This does change the picture a bit, but the notion of Eulerian path still applies.

**Edit #2** (after reading the comments): Your graph has 8 vertices. Each vertex has indegree 8 and outdegree 8, meaning there are 8 incoming and 8 outgoing edges. Since these degrees match up, and the graph is strongly connected, there exists an Eulerian cycle.

A simple, though perhaps not very efficient, way to find one, is this: Start at any vertex. Travel along, always following a previously unused edge, until you can go no further. You will find you are back at the starting point. However, you may not have visited all edges yet. If so, pick a vertex in the cycle you just created which has an unused edge going out. (There must be one somewhere, by connectedness and the matching of in- and outdegrees.) Starting at this vertex, create a new cycle by the same procedure as the first one, avoiding all used edges including those from the first cycle. Again, you will be back where you started when you can go no longer. Join the two cycles into one. Repeat the procedure until all edges are included.

The above is a brief description of a standard construct in graph theory, found in many textbooks on the subject.

**EDIT #3:** Here is one solution.

Listing the nodes, in the order visited:

AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHADGBEHCFAFCHEBGDACEFAHBDFHDHGCGFBFEAECAGEDBHFDCBA

and listing the edges:

A/A A/B B/B B/C C/C C/D D/D D/E E/E E/F F/F F/G G/G G/H H/H H/A A/D
D/G G/B B/E E/H H/C C/F F/A A/F F/C C/H H/E E/B B/G G/D D/A A/C C/E
E/F F/A A/H H/B B/D D/F F/H H/D D/H H/G G/C C/G G/F F/B B/F F/E E/A
A/E E/C C/A A/G G/E E/D D/B B/H H/F F/D D/C C/B B/A

Roughly speaking, the solution is worked out as follows:

1. Once around the circle by step size 0, 1, 0, 1, …
2. Once around by step size 2
3. One step back
4. Once around by step size 2
5. Repeat 4 times: once around by step size 4, one step back (except the last time)
6. Eight times forward, step size 3
7. Eight times forward, step size 5
8. Repeat twice: once around by step size 6, one step back
9. Backwards by step size 1 until we're at A.

No need for Fleury's algorithm.

Comment: I have never heard of the eulerian path. I'm going to research it now and post my findings. thank you very much

Comment: okay, I am reading about this theory and it states:

# of ODD Vertices
 Implication (for a connected graph)
 
0
 There is at least 
one Euler Circuit.
 
1
 THIS IS IMPOSSIBLE! 
2
 There is no Euler Circuit but at least 1 Euler Path.
 
more than 2
 There are no Euler Circuits
or Euler Paths.
 
Does this mean it is impossible to have an Euler path/circuit since I have 8 verticies, which means I have 4 odd verticies?

Comment: the caps is taken straight from a webpage. I didn't mean to appear that I am "yelling" ha ha

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: oh wow. well. I don't know anything about graph theory, so it would be an interesting thing to delve into to understand the subject matter. An eye opener. I thank you for it. :D But as it stands, I have no clue what any of that means... But I will once I do some study on how that all works. The problem is something I am encountering in my game design. Thanks again

Comment: Knowing that the problem does have an answer, the question is now, what is the answer. I don't know how to relate the theory you stated to find the answer I seek, since my knowledge of graph theory is nothing.

Comment: but, it is comforting to know that the answer is obtainable :D that is a victory

Comment: I updated my answer again with an explicit solution.

Comment: Unfortunatly, E/F is used twice in your answer. Which means that with 64 total sets, one set is left out. I'm thinking this is just error transcribing the answer itself. I'm attempting to work out the problem now.

Comment: Reposted the answer using the same method you listed. You just did the second step of the method wrong by using step size 3 instead of step size 2. Thank you very much :) If there is a way I can increase your rep or something, let me know. I have no idea how to do any of those things on this site ha ha.

Comment: A/A, A/B, B/B, B/C, C/C, C/D, D/D, D/E, E/E, E/F, F/F, F/G, G/G, G/H, H/H, H/A, A/C, C/E, E/G, G/A, A/H, H/B, B/D, D/F, F/H, H/D, D/H, H/G, G/C, C/G, G/F, F/B, B/F, F/E, E/A, A/E, E/H, H/C, C/F, F/A, A/D, D/G, G/B, B/E, E/B, B/G, G/D, D/A, A/F, F/C, C/H, H/E, E/C, C/A, A/G, G/E, E/D, D/B, B/H, H/F, F/D, D/C, C/B, B/A

Comment: Actually, I had checked the answer using a simple script. I did get it wrong at first and then fixed it; must have pasted the wrong version after all. Oh well.

Comment: I'm thankful regardless :)